# MTA & HTML Login & Remember Me

Tags: javascript, php, html, remember-me, mta

I'm trying to solve one HTML input bar so I can remember the MTA server
username and password
Login is available here: http://ru1n.eu/index.php?/topic/3-rel-login-panel/
and I found some javascript for remembering and i do not know how to make a login to incorporate it

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if ($('#remember').attr('checked')) 
    {
        var email = $('#email').attr("value");
        var password = $('#password').attr("value");

        // set cookies to expire in 14 days
        $.cookie('email', email, { expires: 14 });
        $.cookie('password', password, { expires: 14 });
        $.cookie('remember', true, { expires: 14 });                
    }
    else
    {
        // reset cookies
        $.cookie('email', null);
        $.cookie('password', null);
        $.cookie('remember', null);
    }

    var remember = $.cookie('remember');
    if (remember == 'true') 
    {
        var email = $.cookie('email');
        var password = $.cookie('password');
        // autofill the fields
        $('#email').attr("value", email);
        $('#password').attr("value", password);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two blocks of code in the same place that should be running in different places. The second block, that checks for cookies and fills the html form - that should be done when the page is finished loading. It looks like you are using jquery, so that might look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var remember = $.cookie('remember');
        if (remember == 'true') 
        {
            var email = $.cookie('email');
            var password = $.cookie('password');
            // autofill the fields
            $('#email').attr("value", email);
            $('#password').attr("value", password);
        }
    });
</script>
```

The other block that sets the cookies should be run when the user submits the form.  For example in some function:

```
function submitForm() {
    if ($('#remember').attr('checked')) 
    {
        var email = $('#email').attr("value");
        var password = $('#password').attr("value");

        // set cookies to expire in 14 days
        $.cookie('email', email, { expires: 14 });
        $.cookie('password', password, { expires: 14 });
        $.cookie('remember', true, { expires: 14 });                
    }
    else
    {
        // reset cookies
        $.cookie('email', null);
        $.cookie('password', null);
        $.cookie('remember', null);
    }

    // now continue with form submission...
}
```

Comment: @Ru1n you mean the answer you posted below? The if/else is right, but updating your values on the checkbox click isn't typical (for example, if they already added an email, clicking remember me will replace it with the one in localstorage). The code should really be run just before form submission. If you're not sure how to do that, you can google or ask a second question.

Comment: Would you not sign up for skype? I do not know how you liked it if you could not write a file, eg save it and paste it into html code <script src="http://mta/local/assets/js/save.js"></script>
so after reconnecting in MTA, the same username and password will not be written back so I just clicked away to enter

Comment: halo? will someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So will the code look like this?
https://ctrlv.cz/XeO3

and this code -var email = $ ('# email')
is what's in the username in the name = "" or id = ""

Answer (score 0):

would such a script not be sent and used?

$(function () {

```
if (localStorage.chkbox && localStorage.chkbox != '') {
    $('#rememberChkBox').attr('checked', 'checked');
    $('#signinId').val(localStorage.username);
    $('#signinPwd').val(localStorage.pass);
} else {
    $('#rememberChkBox').removeAttr('checked');
    $('#signinId').val('');
    $('#signinPwd').val('');
}

$('#rememberChkBox').click(function () {

    if ($('#rememberChkBox').is(':checked')) {
        // save username and password
        localStorage.username = $('#signinId').val();
        localStorage.pass = $('#signinPwd').val();
        localStorage.chkbox = $('#rememberChkBox').val();
    } else {
        localStorage.username = '';
        localStorage.pass = '';
        localStorage.chkbox = '';
    }
});
```

});